# Guests Comments on Buddypress Activity Stream?

Tags: comments, buddypress, activity-streams

Is there any way to allow guests to be able to comment on activity stream posts without having an account?

I tried to find plugins that allowed for this functionality but have come up unsuccessful. If anyone knows of a workaround or a plugin I haven't found that can add this functionality, please let me know. Thank you! :)